# Testing arguments of first call with Sinon/Chai

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai, sinon, sinon-chai

I am trying to match the arguments of functions calls for my unit tests.

The test code is below:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    enrollmentOffer = offerReadModel(EnrollmentOfferStatuses.Accepted, false, undefined, true)
    fakeSearcher = buildFakeReadModelSearcher()
    ...
  })
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore()
  })

  it('does the right query to get the latest child offer', async () => {
    await expect(calculateRenewInfo(enrollmentOffer as EnrollmentOfferReadModel, true)).to.be.fulfilled
    expect(fakeSearcher.filter).to.have.been.calledWithExactly({
      offerType: { eq: OfferTypes.Child },
      enrollmentOfferId: { eq: enrollmentOffer.id },
    })
  })
```

Currently this unit-test errs with:

```
  22) calculateRenewInfo
       does the right query to get the latest child offer:
     AssertionError: expected filter to have been called with exact arguments {
  offerType: { eq: 'child' },
  enrollmentOfferId: { eq: '0a1a6e82-c2ca-48ec-9548-c4b5e4d26653' }
}
{ enrollmentOfferId: { eq: '0a1a6e82-c2ca-48ec-9548-c4b5e4d26653' } } {
  offerType: { eq: 'child' },
  enrollmentOfferId: { eq: '0a1a6e82-c2ca-48ec-9548-c4b5e4d26653' }
}
```

The reason the test fails, I believe, is because there are two calls. The first internal invocation is matching my test arguments. While the second, with arguments being `{ enrollmentOfferId: { eq: '0a1a6e82-c2ca-48ec-9548-c4b5e4d26653' } }`, is not matching it.

Normally, I would do something like: `expect(sinonFake.firstCall).to.have.been.calledWith(...)`. This is however not working for me. For example, if I write `expect(fakeSearcher.filter.firstCall).to.have.been.calledWithExactly(...)`, there is an error `Property 'firstCall' does not exist on type '(filters: FilterFor<OfferReadModel>) => Searcher<OfferReadModel>'.`

We build `fakeSearcher` with:

```
export function buildFakeReadModelSearcher<TReadModel = unknown>(): Partial<Searcher<TReadModel>> {
  const fakeSearcher: Partial<Searcher<TReadModel>> = {}
  fakeSearcher.filter = sinon.fake.returns(fakeSearcher)
  fakeSearcher.afterCursor = sinon.fake.returns(fakeSearcher)
  fakeSearcher.paginatedVersion = sinon.fake.returns(fakeSearcher)
  fakeSearcher.limit = sinon.fake.returns(fakeSearcher)
  fakeSearcher.sortBy = sinon.fake.returns(fakeSearcher)
  fakeSearcher.search = sinon.fake.resolves({ items: [] })
  fakeSearcher.searchOne = sinon.fake.resolves(undefined)
  return fakeSearcher
}
```

Any suggestions/ideas how I could only match the first call, with no or minimal changes to `fakeSearcher`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `buildFakeReadModelSearcher` says it returns a `Partial<Searcher<TReadModel>>` so Typescript doesn't know that `fakeSearcher.filter` is a sinon fake.

You could switch the function to return an object containing all those fakes + the fakeSearcher object as well and then use those fakes directly.

```
export function buildFakeReadModelSearcher<TReadModel = unknown>() {
  const fakeSearcher: Partial<Searcher<TReadModel>> = {}
  const filter = sinon.fake.returns(fakeSearcher)
  const afterCursor = sinon.fake.returns(fakeSearcher)
  const paginatedVersion = sinon.fake.returns(fakeSearcher)
  const limit = sinon.fake.returns(fakeSearcher)
  const sortBy = sinon.fake.returns(fakeSearcher)
  const search = sinon.fake.resolves({ items: [] })
  const searchOne = sinon.fake.resolves(undefined)

  fakeSearcher.filter = filter
  fakeSearcher.afterCursor = afterCursor
  fakeSearcher.paginatedVersion = paginatedVersion
  // ...etc.

  return { fakeSearcher, filter, afterCursor, paginatedVersion, limit, sortBy, search, searchOne }
}

// Then use it like so:
expect(filter.firstCall).to.have.been.calledWithExactly({
  offerType: { eq: OfferTypes.Child },
  enrollmentOfferId: { eq: enrollmentOffer.id },
})
```

Comment: Thank you your suggestion. Your code has `const fakeSearcher` twice. First time - `const fakeSearcher: Partial<Searcher<TReadModel>> = {}` and again `const fakeSearcher: Partial<Searcher<TReadModel>> = {
   filter,
   afterCursor,
   paginatedVersion,
   limit,
   sortBy,
   search,
   searchOne
  }`

Comment: Apologies, I was just in the process of fixing it as I noticed it too :D